# Jackson 2.2 mixins - upgrading from 1.9 new module api

Tags: jackson

In the 1.9 code we used 
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig.addMixInAnnotations and 
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig.addMixInAnnotations. 
In 2.2 it seems this is no longer possible and it must be done via modules.  Is this correct? 
In a module it looks like it will register mix-ins with both serializer and deserialization configurations. In some code I am upgrading there are more serializer configs than deserializer configs and I am wondering if there is a way to duplicate this configuration in 2.2.

Another way of stating my question is can you add mixin's in 2.2 and specify they only apply to serialization etc? or deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on the jackson forum. I had not gotten reply in a few days and timing was running out for me so in this scenario I posted here as another option.

> My assumption for 2.x was that the dominant use case was for mix-ins to apply to both serialization and deserialization, and most common method then was to add them directly via `ObjectMapper`, or using Module methods. Underlying implementation was changed to try to keep objects other than mapper itself immutable; and unification of mix-in settings was more a result of that (and general simplification) than a goal.
>   If you do need separate mix-ins, the best way is to construct separate ObjectMappers. Although `SerializationConfig` and `DeserializationConfig` do keep reference to (potentially) different sets of mix-ins, I don't see methods to make use of this.
>   Also: if separation is necessary, you could file a feature request at github issue tracker (for project jackson-databind). I don't know off-hand how easy it would be to add support back in, but it's worth suggesting if it is something you really need.The challenge at implementation level is that mix-ins are a fundamental feature that must be set before any actual serialization or deserialization (since it affects the way serializers/deserializers are built; and due to caching, effects will last even if mix-in set was modified).